# What can be a feature in BDD

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I have done some research over information related to below question, but couldn't get right information.

I have a scenario where a user creates some data using a create rest API and saves it in backend. Then, the user retrieves the saved data using a get API later to validate the data that's saved in the backend as part of create API.

Now, can creating the data in backend and retrieving the data be combined as a feature? or should there be two features – one for creating the data and other for retrieving the data? If it can be done in both ways – what are advantages of one over other?

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific rule of thumb how one would group business logic by `features`. However there are some technical details making your entire code behave differently depending on how you group features. Here is some advice:

- `Background` is defined once per feature. So if your tests require different background it probably makes sense to put it to different features (probably testing `get` would imply you have to insert some data before the test which is not necessary for testing `put`)
- If you're not "gluing" your files explicitly they are taken depending on the position of your runner classes within the package structure. So that you can play with different configuration not only on gherkin level but also on the level of the particular test framework (like JUnit and TestNg). This is very much like the previous point but only using the capabilities provided by underlying unit test framework.
- If you need to run your tests in parallel, sometimes the way how you group things by features also matters. When you run Cucumber-JUnit4 in parallel, **it runs each feature file in parallel** but all the scenarios inside a single feature in a sequence.
- You would also might need to tag some tests in some special way. If there is a lot of such tests it makes sense to put sthem in a spearate file and apply the tag to entire feature rather than to tag each test individually.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have two separate scenarios to validate the POST and the GET. In that way, you have better visibility of two separate APIs. In the future during execution, you would also be able to know by looking at the title which API works and which one is broken (if any). You don't need to go into the step definitions and check whether the scenario for the POST API also includes the validation for GET as well or if that's a separate scenario.

So, one scenario to validate the POST and whether it returns `201 Created`. And another scenario to validate the GET.